# How to fix onclick Function is not working using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Anyone can help me? this is my problem. When I tried to click the `button` using this function `$(".btn_cellophane").on("click",function(){});` I did not get any response or even the error. I guess the `onclick` function is not working. Here's my code below.

**METHOD CALLING**

```
$(".btn_cellophane").on("click",function(){
     alert("Tester true");
         if($(this).hasClass("btn-warning")){
              $(this).removeClass("btn-warning");
              $(this).addClass("btn-success");

              // add_amount_for_cellophane();

         }else if($(this).hasClass("btn-success")){
              $(this).addClass("btn-warning");
              $(this).removeClass("btn-success");

              // add_amount_for_cellophane();
         }
});
```

**CONTENT DISPLAY**

```
var html_cellophane = "";
$.each(data, function(key,product){

        $.each(product.sizes, function(pro_id,variant){

             if(variant.prod_type == 1){
                   var label = (variant.size+" "+variant.unit).toUpperCase();
                   var var_id = variant.variant_id;
                   var price = variant.price;

                       html_cellophane += '<div>'+
                                                '<label>Cellophane ('+price+' pesos)</label>'+
                                           '</div>'+
                                           '<br/>'+
                                           '<div style="width: 100%;">'+
                                                 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn_cellophane" id="cp_id_btn" data-var_id="'+var_id+'" data-qty="'+1+'" data-price="'+price+'">1</button>'+
                                                 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn_cellophane" id="cp_id_btn" data-var_id="'+var_id+'" data-qty="'+2+'" data-price="'+price+'">2</button>'+
                                                 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn_cellophane" id="cp_id_btn" data-var_id="'+var_id+'" data-qty="'+3+'" data-price="'+price+'">3</button>'+
                                                 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn_cellophane" id="cp_id_btn" data-var_id="'+var_id+'" data-qty="'+4+'" data-price="'+price+'">4</button>'+
                                                 '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn_cellophane" id="cp_id_btn" data-var_id="'+var_id+'" data-qty="'+5+'" data-price="'+price+'">5</button>'+
                                                  '<hr>'+                                        
                                           '</div>';

              }                                     

         });                                                 


});                  

$('.btn_cellophane_div ').html(html_cellophane);
```

Comment: `.btn_cellophane` element does not exist at the time you're attaching the event. jQuery always returns an object, that's why the error isn't fired.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery this might help you.

Comment: have you put your click handler in $(document).ready() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created the button dynamically. So while you are attaching the event listener the element doesn't exists till then. So you have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for working the click event.

Just change your event listener like this-

```
$(document).on("click",".btn_cellophane", function(){});
```